# using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync in Xamarin app. Can I move my API out of Azure?

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms app using "Azure Mobile Sync" and using these DLLs:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;
```

I want to move my API out of Azure and into my own shared hosting account.  This I know how to do but I do not know if "Azure Mobile Sync" will still work if my API is not hosted in Azure.

REF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO Wyland! Are you using MSSQL in your shared hosting account?